# Firebase return data sometimes can be parse, sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, object

my problem solved.It's complicated. Let's us focus on this phenomenon.

[image: my data structure]

I have multiple layers, and I use tested Id : 1,2,3,4 , so firebase think my data id structure suppose to be :1,2,3,4,5...   But the respond array or to say every array must have an index with 0 ..

It returns a 0 with null, cause I don't have 0 ,firebase made for me.(Suddenly,I seems like feelling the love with AI. To be honest...)

[image]

However, the real id is not '1,2,3,4' , I randomly enter an id '123455'.....

Firebase turns to be confused and realizes that 'oh! ,you data structure should not be an array. Let's try an deeply nest object...'

[image: deeply nested objects data structure]

---

Problem: when id = 1,2,3 , firebase make '0' for you
[image: when apply typeof() to it , it returns 'object' . However it actually an array...]

### when apply typeof() to it , it returns 'object' . However it actually an array... You can even use forEach() to it???

So how can I get the data return?

Answer (score 0):

Because Javascript sometimes not reliable ... on typeof()..

```
const data  = await res.json();

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(data));
```

if it's an array . it will show [object Array] ,
if it's an object . it will show [object Object]

You can write two ways to parse data...